# passing a function into JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently studying javascript by following the series "you dont know js".

In the section "types & grammer", when discussing "JSON.stringify" function, the author mentioned

> ```
> var a = {
>   b: 42,
>   c: "42",
>   d: [11,22,33]
> };
>
> JSON.stringify( a, ["b","c"] ); // "{"b":42,"c":"42"}"
>
> JSON.stringify( a, function(k,v){
>   if (k !== "c") return v;
> } );
> // "{"b":42,"d":[11,22,33]}"
> ```
>
> Note: In the function replacer case, the key argument k is undefined
>   for the first call (where the a object itself is being passed in). The
>   if statement filters out the property named "c". Stringification is
>   recursive, so the [1,2,3] array has each of its values (1, 2, and 3)
>   passed as v to replacer, with indexes (0, 1, and 2) as k.

So I have came out with the following code, aimed at removing the value `22` from the `JSON.stringify` result

```js
var a = {
  b: 42,
  c: "42",
  d: [11, 22, 33]
};

var result = JSON.stringify(a, function(k, v) {
  //since each index 0, 1, 2 of property "c" will be passed into function as "k", 
  //therefore if "k !== 1" should filter out value 22
  if (k !== 1) {
    return v;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

I was expecting the result to be `"{"b":42,"c":"42","d":[11,33]}"`.

However, the result was instead `"{"b":42,"c":"42","d":[11,22,33]}"` (as you can see, the value 22 at index 1 of property c is not filtered out)

Did I miss understood what the author said? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kaddath — No. The replacer function is run recursively.

Comment: @Quentin thx, i was not focused, it is written in the question! you learn each day..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property names are always *strings*. `1 !== "1"`. Compare to a string instead of a number.

```js
var a = {
  b: 42,
  c: "42",
  d: [11, 22, 33]
};

var result = JSON.stringify(a, function(k, v) {
  if (k !== "1") {       // "1" not 1 here
    return v;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Quentin, thank you very much for the answer.  Do you mind if I ask a follow up question. I was wondering what the author meant by `the key argument k is undefined for the first call (where the a object itself is being passed in)`. Why is the object `a` itself been passed to as the argument to the `anonymous function`? What is the purpose of such logic?

Comment: I can't think of any uses off the top of my head. (Which doesn't mean there aren't any.)

Comment: Sometimes I just dont get how javascript works lol. Just wondering, do you happen to know where I can find the implementation (i.e. the source code) of "JSON.stringify" method? Would love to know how it is implemented internally.

Comment: Who's implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The key will be string representing the property name and when iterating through the array properties it will be a string representing the array indexes.

The JSON.stringify iterator work in a way that the function is being executed for all elements in the object starting from the top element itself.

For example having the object you showed:

```
var a = {
  b: 42,
  c: "42",
  d: [11,22,33]
};
```

The function supplied for the JSON.stringify will run for the following keys and values:

- The all object `{b: 42, c: "42", d: [11,22,33]}` doesn't have a key since it the top level element, so in this case the `k` variable will be `undefined`.
- The `42` value accessed by the key `b`.
- The `"42"` value accessed by the key `c`.
- The `[11,22,33]` value accessed by the key `d`.
- The `11` value accessed by the key `0`.
- The `22` value accessed by the key `1`.
- The `33` value accessed by the key `2`.